# why Db1.DataBind() property not working?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

```
cmd = New SqlCommand
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Mod", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 4
con.Open()
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
Db1.DataSource = dr
Db1.DataBind()
```

why Db1.DataBind() property not working?

Comment: Is this all of your code? You haven't set the CommandText, nor set the connection property of `cmd` - how does it know what to execute and where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SqlConnection conn=new SqlConnection(your db connestionString);
con.Open()
SqlCommand cmd = New SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection=conn;
//here Iguess you are trying to pass this parameter to sql strored procedure.
//So first set cmd.Commanndtype to sproc
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Mod", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 4
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
Db1.DataSource = dr
Db1.DataBind()
```